# Rearrange table in CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a table with 2 columns as sketched below. I want to rearrange/break the table e.g after 2 rows, so that the following lines continue on the right side.

```
[1][2]     [1][2][5][6]
[3][4] =>  [3][4][7][8]
[5][6]
[7][8]
```

Is that possible in pure CSS?

Changing it in the HTML Code is not an option.
A solution running only in normal browsers would be acceptable.

EDIT:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5814bskk/).

I want to break the table after 9 rows (half).
In the example: Break after the line containing 'strict2' so that the line containing 'basic3' is right next to the line with 'basic'.

EDIT2:
Since a solution in CSS is not possible, I use a JS solution to break the table.

Comment: So, you basically want to break up the table after n-th line and set it right to the other table, just like it were another table, set with float: right;, correctly?

Comment: Use 'display:table cell' for first four tables

Comment: Can you show your code? HTML and CSS please.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please clarify what exactly it is what you want? Could you maybe add some HTML code to show what your table looks like and possibly add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see what is going on?

Comment: So, dependant on what you want to achieve, you might try to fiddle around with the nth-child property: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: jsfiddle & clarification added.

Comment: this is not doable in pure css I think,, why dont you do it in javascript?

Comment: When _changing HTML Code is not an option_ there is no way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split the row after count of 9 and then display the rest in a new table

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $secLevelTable = $(".secLevelTable");
    var splitBy = 9;
    var rows = $secLevelTable.find("tr").slice(splitBy);
    var $secondTable = $(".secLevelTable").parent().append("<table class='secondTable'><tbody></tbody></table>");
    $secondTable.find("tbody").append(rows);
    $secLevelTable.find("tr").slice(splitBy).remove();
});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5814bskk/1/)